# How can i get CPU, GPU, Disk used, free info in Apple Devices

Tags: ios, memory-management

I want to get all above info for my app that tends to manage and free memory and draft data cached on iPhone or iPad device. Seems like i have to face some private and forbidden apple API?

Comment: i saw such a code in github.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen: oh god, please send me the github link. Thankyou so much

Comment: check links in answer.

Answer (score 1):

check this [[iOS-System-Services]](https://github.com/Shmoopi/iOS-System-Services) and [[GBDeviceInfo]](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBDeviceInfo)

** Results of a simple google of "github ios device info"

Comment: if this solves the problem, please accept the answer.